# Can two different FIM products communicate with each other

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, federated-identity

Not sure if I am asking this question correctly.
I have a question regarding Federated Identity management. If two organization want to establish a trust between each other, one as Identity provider while other one as service provider. If the organization that act as identity provider decided to purchase IBM FIM, that doesn’t’ mean service provider should also have IBM FIM? I am assuming it can be another vendor as long as both can communicate by exchanging SAML tokens?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAML is an open standard implemented by many vendors. Assuming that IBM FIM generates valid SAML assertions as the Identity Provider (IdP), the Service Provider (SP) can integrate any vendor product that is compliant with the SAML specification.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question.